# Why does my text align vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
     background-color:green;
     height:500px;
     width:500px;
     margin:auto;
     border-radius:50%;
     overflow:hidden;
     padding:300px;
     border: 4px solid red;
     box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text .</p> 
</div>
```

Hello, I would like to know how am I supposed to make this text go vertically and don't move out of the div? I've already tried doing vertical alignment but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: padding : 300px .... 300px right + 300px left > 500px height == line break  + overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by using flexbox.

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div><p>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text .</p> </div>
```

Comment: Not everything needs a flexbox, his goal is quite easy to achieve with just the right padding.

Comment: It doesn't. But this way you neither need a child element nor you need to adjust your padding every time your content changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set CSS setting `box-sizing` to `border-box`? If so, this is the reason. Your padding is too big, so the width & height are small. You can decrease the padding, or set the CSS setting `box-sizing` to `content-box` especially for this element.